# Testing User Model (Devise Authentication) with MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, tdd, minitest

I'm trying to test user model, for which I've devise authentication.

The problem I'm facing is,
1. Having 'password'/'password_confirmation' fields in fixtures is giving me invalid column 'password'/'password_confirmation' error.

2. If I remove these columns from fixture and add in user_test.rb

   ```
   require 'test_helper'

   class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase


         def setup
           @user = User.new(name: "example user",
                            email: "example@example.com",
                            password: "Test123",
                            work_number: '1234567890',
                            cell_number: '1234567890')
         end

         test "should be valid" do
           assert @user.valid?
         end

         test "name should be present" do
           @user.name = "Example Name "
           assert @user.valid?
         end

       end
   ```

The error I'm getting is:

```
  test_0001_should be valid                                       FAIL (0.74s)
Minitest::Assertion:         Failed assertion, no message given.
        test/models/user_test.rb:49:in `block in <class:UserTest>'

  test_0002_name should be present                                FAIL (0.01s)
Minitest::Assertion:         Failed assertion, no message given.
        test/models/user_test.rb:54:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


Fabulous run in 0.75901s
2 tests, 2 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I'm wondering why my user object is not valid?

Thanks

Comment: print errors in models by puts "errors = #{@user.errors}"
and see which validation is causing the failure.

Comment: Original answer is password_conformation is not a column. You have to place only password field in fixtures with encrypted password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a work around after some investigation like below:
Add a helper method for fixture:

```
# test/helpers/fixture_file_helpers.rb
module FixtureFileHelpers
  def encrypted_password(password = 'password123')
    User.new.send(:password_digest, password)
  end
end

# test/test_helper.rb
require './helpers/fixture_file_helpers.rb'
ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.context_class.send :include, FixtureFileHelpers
```

And make fixture like this:

```
default:
  email: 'default@example.com'
  name: "User name"
  encrypted_password: <%= encrypted_password %>
  work_number: '(911) 235-9871'
  cell_number: '(911) 235-9871'
```

And use this fixture as user object in user test.

```
def setup
    @user = users(:default)
end
```

Comment: Simply use: `encrypted_password: <%= User.new.send(:password_digest, 'password123') %>,` in fixture