# testing devise model with minitest undefined method 'valid'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, minitest, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to make a simple validity test to a user model generated through devise. my test/models/user_test.rb file looks like this

```
require 'test_helper'

 class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase


 def setup
  @user = User.new(email: "admin@example.com", password: "foobar" )
 end

 test should be valid do
  assert @user.valid?
 end

end
```

the error i'm getting is:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/models/user_test.rb:10:in `<class:UserTest>': undefined local variable or method `valid' for UserTest:Class (NameError)
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/test/models/user_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
```

I saw in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388578/testing-user-model-devise-authentication-with-minitest/29726865#29726865) that they manege to do a very similar test.

i completed the rails tutorial from which i learned to create a fully functional user mvc system but now i want to try to do it faster with devise.

thanks.

Comment: `should be valid` needs to be in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write: `"should be valid"`
Look here for example [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests)

Answer (score 0):

I like following syntax:

```
def  test_should_be_valid
  ##Your code
end
```

A method starts with "test_".